# Show line number object is destructed

Tags: c++, trace, line-numbers

I'm implementing a trace mechanism that outputs a log line when a function is entered and upon exit (when the trace object is destructed).  I would be interested in also outputting the line number the scope exits but not sure how to accomplish this since the object is destroyed upon exit.  Obviously `__LINE__` in the destructor won't work since it will just output the destructor's line number.

Comment: The scope ends at the closing brace of the function (unless you're talking about temporaries that last for the duration of some expression). Do you really need to log that?

Comment: @jrok I suppose I meant to say to print the line number that *caused* the scope to exit such as by a return statement.

Comment: I see. Maybe this: `#define LOG_RETURN(x) return (std::clog << __LINE__), (x);` :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to dump the stack trace, how it is done is platform/compiler dependant. For Visual Studio, you can use the [DbgHelp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679309) library, though the complete code to print a stack trace is quite lengthy.